# How to set status code in Perl, similary on the way, like it works in PHP?

Tags: php, perl, http-headers

What is the analog of this PHP code, which would do the same in Perl?

```
<?php 
if (false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '(foo|bar)')) {
    header('410 Gone');
} 
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps `print "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone\n";`

Comment: Indeed it should work. Do you have an example how to accomplish the check of REQUEST_URI for certain strings?

Comment: If you're using `mod_perl` it may be described in the documentation (https://perl.apache.org/). If you're calling `perl` scripts from `php`, you'll probably have to pass the necessary data as parameters to the `perl` script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP user, but `strpos` looks like Perl's [index](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index), which returns -1 (an out-of-bounds position) if it doesn't find the sting.

```
if( -1 != index $some_string, $substring ) { ... }
```